# Eating from Subway restaurant

Tags: food

Can we eat from subway in a non Muslim country for example in New York they have many subways the restaurant across the USA

Answer (score 1):

It’s best not to, though if they have a vegetarian option it should be fine (just be sure to request they use a separate knife upon slicing your sandwich or anything else so that the knife they use when slicing meat doesn’t touch your sandwich).

Answer (score 0):

Whenever me and my family go out of country we only eat from halal certified restaurants or if we are in a Muslim country we eat from anywhere. It is best not to eat meat in a non Muslim country although you can always eat seafood such as fish and shrimp, seafood is always halal.